# structure data not reflecting

Tags: google-search, search-box, google-sitelink-searchbox

I've added structured data to this page: sitelinks search box
https://www.indzola.com/

The Google structured data test tool confirms the structured data.

But Google search results are not showing the structured data:
https://www.google.co.in/search?q=indzola.com&oq=indzola.com&aqs=chrome..69i60l3j69i57j69i60j69i61.5141j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks,

yash jain